# Find orthogonal matrices such that $P^TAP$ is diagonal (dim=2)

Tags: linear-algebra

Let

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
-5 & 12 \\ 12 & 5
\end{bmatrix}.$$

I found the eigenvalues $13$ and $-13$, and the eigenvectors $[2,3]^T$ and $[3,-2]^T$. However, the matrix with them as columns transposed, times $A$, times that matrix is not diagonal.

I'm not sure why I expected it to be (I am checking my answers)  and I sense I may have a huge misconception about what I am doing. Please help me find where and why I've gone wrong. And also some resources (questions and notes) for practice, and that I may learn from.

**Addendum**

I may be less wrong that I thought, my matrix of eigenvectors can be symmetric if I place it in a certain way,if I place it the other way, I get negative my first answer.

Not sure what I got wrong, I'd still love an answer if one is going.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

- Find the eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors of the matrix.
- Define the columns of $P$ as the eigenvectors from the previous step.
- Since the matrix A is symmetric, you will find that $P^T = P^{-1}$.
- Write $A = P \cdot J \cdot P^T$, or $J = P^T \cdot A \cdot P$

**Spoiler**

> $$J = \begin{bmatrix}-13 & 0 \\ 0 & 13\end{bmatrix}; P = \begin{bmatrix}-3 & 2 \\ 2 & 3\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: It's nice that this works, at A-level I found it "lovely" and interesting, I'd like more proofs now and things, what's the subject? Can you recommend a book?

Comment: Research Jordan Normal Form. Regards

Comment: You're missing one point: eigenvectors need to be normalized! @AlecTeal The [Schur decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_decomposition) is more appropriate for this than the Jordan normal form.

Comment: Great use of the Spoiler! +1